# Font not found with angular-cli, sass and materialize-css

Tags: angular, angular-cli, materialize

I'm working in a project when I'm using angular-cli and materialize-css, for the styles I'm using sass by default. When I import the sass files from the lib:
 @import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize";

**The app find the styles but not the roboto fonts**

I tried to put it directly in the styles inside of the angular-cli.json file and I have the same error.
**I think that materialize-css sass cannot resolve the Fonts path.**

Answer (score 0):

> The Roboto font will be not automatically loaded by AngularJS Material
>   itself.
>
> The developer is responsible for loading all fonts used in their
>   application.

**You can host it yourself or include it from Google Fonts:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
```

please see the link.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/typography

**If you want to use NPM
you can use Webpack+NPM**

For more info please see the link

https://github.com/pablorsk/test-generator-fountain-webapp-angular-material

```
$ npm install --save-dev file-loader
$ npm install --save roboto-fontface
```

Hope this helps